# Validity of the arclength definition of the four-velocity vector

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, velocity, relativity

In many textbooks & papers the four-velocity vector has the standard definition $$u^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}$$
where $\tau$ is the proper time.

However, some textbooks define the four-velocity vector with an alternative parameter, the arclength s, such that $$u^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{ds}$$
Which seems ok since $ds^2=c^2 d\tau^2$.

But if the arclength is not defined along a null-geodesic (curve), then can the four-velocity vector still be defined with arclength being the parameter?

Or in other words is the latter definiton even valid (for all curves), is it still a "four-velocity vector" and what are the advantages of using this alternative form?

Comment: $d\tau$ is also zero along a null geodesic.

Comment: Are there any references about the second definition? In your case, wouldn't it give you different units?

Comment: @SpiralRain The second definition is used in a book called "Tesors, Relativity and Cosmology", it does seem to give different units which in turn gives different expressions for several quantities. (e.g. the standard definition of the energy momentum tensor of a matter distribution $T^{kn}=(pc^2+\rho)u^ku^n-g^{kn}p$ becomes $T^{kn}=(p+\rho c^2) u^k u^n- g^{kn}p$ instead) so I suspect that it's only being used in this weird book but not anywhere else....

Comment: @G. Smith Ok what about the validity of the second definition?